# MySQL Sort two columns in ascending order

Tags: mysql

I hope this is not a duplicate question. Is it possible to sort a table like below? I am trying to sort by two columns `position` and `checked` in ascending order.

```
+----------+----------+---------+
|   item   | position | checked |
+----------+----------+---------+
| apple    |        1 |       0 |
| banana   |        5 |       0 |
| coconut  |        2 |       1 |
| dog      |        0 |       0 |
| elephant |        4 |       1 |
| fox      |        3 |       0 |
+----------+----------+---------+

+----------+----------+---------+
|   item   | position | checked |
+----------+----------+---------+
| dog      |        0 |       0 |
| apple    |        1 |       0 |
| fox      |        3 |       0 |
| banana   |        5 |       0 |
| coconut  |        2 |       1 |
| elephant |        4 |       1 |
+----------+----------+---------+
```

I tried using the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY position AND checked;
```

However, this only sorts it by one columns.

```
+----------+----------+---------+
|   item   | position | checked |
+----------+----------+---------+
| apple    |        1 |       0 |
| banana   |        5 |       0 |
| dog      |        0 |       0 |
| fox      |        3 |       0 |
| coconut  |        2 |       1 |
| elephant |        4 |       1 |
+----------+----------+---------+
```

I tried using `ASC` and a comma instead of `AND`, and so on, but none of them worked. Is this even possible?

**EDIT**
I tried gvee's solution and here is what I get.

```
+----------+----------+---------+
|   item   | position | checked |
+----------+----------+---------+
| dog      |        0 |       0 |
| apple    |        1 |       0 |
| coconut  |        2 |       1 |
| fox      |        3 |       0 |
| elephant |        4 |       1 |
| banana   |        5 |       0 |
+----------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: So you treid `ASC` and a comma and doesn't work? How it doesn't work?

Comment: For example, I tried the answer gvee posted, but it sorts by `positions`, but `checked` remain unsorted. In other words, only one column is sorted, and the other is not.

Comment: Sorry, I added it in the edit now.

Comment: @CookieMonster note that my answer sorts by `checked` **first**. It doesn't look like you used my suggestion correctly.

Comment: It now works! I did not try your answer correctly. Sorry. =\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
....
ORDER
    BY checked  ASC
     , position ASC
```

Comment: I already tried this, but this does not work. It sorts by `position`, but `checked` is not sorted.

Comment: @CookieMonster - It is working fine [**here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7432a/1)

Comment: Are you sure about that? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1a87c/1 I fear you've not told us the whole story!

Comment: Oops... I should've checked your answer correctly... I had `position` and `checked` swapped when I copied your answer! After correcting it, it works now. This is very embarrassing. =\